# How to use chained Promises calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement a simple login function.

```js
module.exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
    let loggedin_user;
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email.toLowerCase()})
    .then(user => {
        if(!user){
            throw ('Invalid e-mail or password');
        }
        loggedin_user = user;
        return bcryptjs.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    })
    .then(res => {
        if(!res){
            return res.status(401).json('Invalid e-mail or password')
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({
            id: loggedin_user._id,
            role: loggedin_user.role
        }, process.env.JWT_KEY, { expiresIn: '24h' });
        
        return res.status(200).json({
            token: token,
            role: loggedin_user.role,
            expires_in: 24*60*60})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return res.status(401).json(err);
    })

}
```

My code works great until it reaches the last return part, this part:

```js
return res.status(200).json({
    token: token,
    role: loggedin_user.role,
    expires_in: 24*60*60,
})
```

It doesn't return anything instead it jumps to the catch block, although it console logs that javascript object that I need to return, it logs it right before the return statement.

What's the problem?

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: message : "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/login: 401 Unauthorized"

Comment: What's the success/failure values of `return bcryptjs.compare(req.body.password, user.password)`

Comment: res equals true

Answer (score 0):

You should log the error message in the catch to see what the error is.

I'd suspect `req.body` or `user` may be undefined, and checking the properties `email` and `password` could result in an error.

Comment: No they are all defined , code is working great until this statement
```
return res.status(200).json({
            token: token,
            role: loggedin_user.role,
            expires_in: 24*60*60})
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I don't catch any error to your code. Maybe issue is with your password, but I am not sure.

Any way to simplify things and check the same, I modified your code as below. Try this and let me know the output. To deal with Promises, Async/Await is better.

```js
module.exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email.toLowerCase() });

    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).json('Invalid e-mail');
    }

    const checkPass = await bcryptjs.compare(req.body.password, user.password);

    if (!checkPass) {
        res.status(401).json('Invalid password');
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user._id,
        role: user.role,
      },
      process.env.JWT_KEY,
      { expiresIn: '24h' }
    );

    res.status(200).json({
      token: token,
      role: user.role,
      expires_in: 24 * 60 * 60,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: I just prefer then and catch , it's no problem to use async await I just need to know why it's not working

Comment: Have you tried the above code to check if it is working? If it does then I can re-evaluate your code.

Comment: it's working ! , what's the difference between it and my code ? , it is just then and catch approach

Comment: I figured it out
the problem is I was using 'res' for the result of bcryptjs.compare while usin res.status at the same time , that's awkward